# Unable to receive UDP Packets from a specific IP

Tags: android

I am trying to connect to a datalink that sends UDP packet.  These packets are not 'broadcasted.'  (I understand that there is two ways to send a UDP backet, to broadcast such that any machine can receive on the network, or to send to a specific IP...my understanding is limited to this, but I know that they are sent to a specific IP).

I am unable to receive the packets on my Android app I am testing with (Galaxy S3...internet permission has been enabled in the Manifest). I am binding to the host machine (IP) and its associated port.  The packet traffic is seen in WireShark.

Here is my code.  Anything glaring I am omitting?

```
try {
Log.d("UDP", "1");
            DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket();
            Log.d("UDP", "2");
            InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(UDP_IP);
            Log.d("UDP", "2a");
            serverSocket.connect(address, UDP_SERVER_PORT);
            Log.d("UDP", "2b");
            serverSocket.setSoTimeout(5000); //5 sec wait for the client to connect
            Log.d("UDP", "3");
            byte[] data = new byte[1024]; 
            Log.d("UDP", "4");
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length);
            Log.d("UDP", "5");
            Log.d("UDP", "S: Receiving...");
            serverSocket.receive(packet);
            //lock.release();
            retVar = 1;
            Log.d(" Received Packet", "Good");
        } 
    catch (Exception e) {
      Log.e("UDP", "S: Error", e);
    }
```